# CakePHP with PHPUnit fails when using command line testing

Tags: php, cakephp, testing, command-line, phpunit

I'm using CakePHP 2.x and installed PHPUnit to do my testing.
Everything was working well until I uploaded my app to my hosting. 
If I test it through the web (/test.php), it works fine.
But if I use `cake test app XXXXXX`, it gives me this error:

```
Configure::bootstrap() - CORE/Cake/Core/Configure.php, line 92
require - CORE/Cake/bootstrap.php, line 175
ShellDispatcher::_bootstrap() - CORE/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 136
ShellDispatcher::_initEnvironment() - CORE/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 98
ShellDispatcher::__construct() - CORE/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 54
ShellDispatcher::run() - CORE/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php, line 65
[main] - CORE/Cake/Console/cake.php, line 49</pre></div></pre>
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in /blablablablabla/cake/app/Vendor/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 71
```

In Autoload.php:

```
70. spl_autoload_register(
71.   function ($class)
72.   {
```

I didn't install PHPUnit though pear, I used the standalone plugin option (https://github.com/Hyra/PHPUnit-Cake2), but locally it works fine.

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in
>   /blablablablabla/cake/app/Vendor/PHPUnit/Autoload.php on line 71

Did you check what line or around line 71 of Autoload.php is? It clearly tells you that there is a syntax error.

Check if short tags are enabled locally but not on the server. If short tags are used in your application get rid of them. You don't want to use short tags for exactly the kind of issue you have right now.

Comment: Show more of the code or check it yourself, somewhere in that file must be a syntax error. These three lines alone don't help.

Comment: But locally is working fine. It is just not working on my hosting. And this file is the same

Comment: Compare the php versions and name them here.

Comment: Local is 5.5.3 and hosting's is 5.3.27

Comment: PHPUnit's version is 2.4.3

Comment: Update phpunit and your webservers php version as well, they're both very old. Your phpunit is totally outdated. Most recent version is 3.7.